# Nextjs is installing resources and media and prevents any action on page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Nextjs 10.1 (just upgraded from 10.0.4) to build a project for my company, and I have a weird issue. When loading a page (or navigating) no link will work unless all resources and media on the page are fully installed behind the scene in browser. [image]

As you can see in the above image, the video is being installed in-browser while it's idle and I haven't clicked on it. This is causing a bigger issue, if I click on any link, the action waits until the resources are all installed and then the page navigates to the other page.

Notes:

- I have the storage gateway on the same domain as my application.
- On localhost, the resources are being installed but the application is not being blocked. So the blocking issue is happening on production only.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue with Nextjs is that it's expecting you to use lazy loaded resources, so just use any popular lazy loading library and that should resolve the issue.

Note: by the time of this comment was posted, there was an issue with built-in Image component that it causes memory leaks and wastes resources. So, don't use it.